# net core docker compose does register file changes

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I trying to make a simple docker-compose file to run net-core 2.2, it looks like it is working, but when I make a change to the file it does not get re compiled and therefore I can't see any changes made.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

# Create directory for the app source code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/api
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

# Copy the source and restore dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/api
RUN dotnet restore

# Expose the port and start the app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--urls", "http://*:5000;http://*:5001"]
CMD [ "dotnet", "run" ]
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
      build:
        context: . 
        dockerfile: docker/dotnet/Dockerfile
      networks:
        - default
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
      volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
```

The project is the default `dotnet new webapi -o playground --no-https`

Any ideas or help? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the file change info is not reaching dotnet inside docker (would have to look at kernel internals to understand why the docker namespace is not getting this info - when its running inotify)..  (if you're on a linux host running docker - it should be doable)..

There is a feature request for docker about this:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18246

The best workaround in that thread is to run: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting (ie. run nodemon -L inside your docker) - it can also handle restarting none-node applications).

otherwise here's how others have done instead (making vscode rebuild it for you on F5):
https://github.com/Microsoft/generator-docker/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

By default `docker-compose` won't rebuild the image. You can tell it to do that by running `docker-compose up --build`. See [Expose docker-compose up --build flag](https://github.com/xeger/docker-compose/pull/39).

Comment: but that breaks the entire concept of docker, I never seem that issue in other languages like python, JS or php... odd that it can't not detect changes and require to re build the containers all the time